# I do understand Ohm's law but, how will current increase if voltage is a constant and resistance keeps decreasing?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, electrical-engineering

An increase in current would mean an increase in kinetic energy of Coulumbs of charge flowing in the wire, so how does removing resistance give kinetic enrgy to the coulumbs flowing in the wire, how does removing resistance increase current if voltage is constant ( voltage causes current as it gives energy to the electrons ) for eg. I = V/R, 3A = 3v/1 ohm,6A = 3v/0.5 ohm, 12 A = 3v/0.25 ohm. Please correct my understanding if it is wrong.

Comment: In terms of energy, I would compare it with a box sitting on an inclined plane, where the voltage source is equivalent to the incline plane, the speed of the box sliding down is the current, and the friction between the box and the plane is the resistance. More friction, the box moves slower down the plane. Less friction, and the box moves faster, even though the incline plane doesnt change. Voltage causes current by the same mechanism, hence less resistance means more current flow. Thinking in terms of potential and kinetic energy is probably just going to cause more confusion at this point.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I couldn't find a good SE article for what you are looking for. One can give a number of different explanations for the resistance of metals and semiconductors. The most simple one is the Drude model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model) which explains the resistance with (classical) collision of electrons with the metal's atoms. This can be further refined with quantum mechanics but in essence all models predict that the electric field accelerates electrons for a short distance and then they lose momentum and energy in collisions, which becomes heat.

Comment: Generally, the kinetic energy of the electrons in a wire  is negligible. The electron drift velocity is very small. Any kinetic energy they gain is almost immediately converted to heat. Ohm's law captures the "almost".

Answer (score 0):

> how does removing resistance give kinetic enrgy to the coulumbs flowing in the wire, how does removing resistance increase current if voltage is constant

I am not generally a big fan of the Drude model, but conceptually it is useful here. According to the Drude model $$\vec J =\frac{nq^2 \tau}{m}\vec E$$ where $\vec J$ is the current density, $\vec E$ is the E field, $n$, $q$, and $m$ are the charge carrier number density, charge, and mass respectively, and $\tau$ is the time between collisions with the lattice.

Suppose that resistance is decreased by increasing $\tau$. That means there is more time between collisions. So under a fixed E field the charge carriers accelerate for a longer time before hitting the lattice. Because of that longer acceleration they also have a higher average velocity and therefore a higher current density.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the formula correctly. You do understand that.

I'm not sure that thinking of it as the kinetic energy of electrons will be useful to you. But if you can apply the formula correctly, you don't need to understand what's really going on.

Still, we can look at how past physicists have thought of it. Before they knew about electrons, they thought of electric charge as a sort of fluid that could flow through wires like water through a pipe. Voltage was the force that pushed the fluid, and amperage was the rate that the fluid actually moved. Resistance was like a filter that resisted the movement of the fluid and slowed it down. The higher the pressure difference, the faster the fluid moved through the filter.

But then they found out about electrons. It's electrons that flow through the wire. Amperage is the rate that electrons pass any cross-section of the wire. Voltage is the electromagnetic force that pushes them. Resistance is whatever-it-is that slows them down.

But then when they looked at it in detail, the more they found out the more confused they got. Is it a few electrons traveling fast, or a lot of electrons traveling slow? When you look at how many electrons there are in a mole of copper wire, it's HUGE. Averaged over all the electrons, 1 ampere moves them on average very very slowly.

But if they can move at relativistic speeds, then things like magnetism etc can be explained by that. It's tempting to believe it's a few of them moving very fast.

They calculated that electrons DO move at relativistic speed through copper, in random directions. Voltage gives them a slight tendency to travel more in one direction than another.

But assuming they move slow, still the electric field moves fast. How can electrons moving very very slowly out of battery terminals heat up a light bulb filament meters away? The electric field must be mostly independent of the motion of the electrons.

The electrons all repel each other. Mathematically we can assume all the electrons are on the two-dimensional outside skin of the wire, and we get results that way which match experiment. Are there no moving electrons inside the wire? Well maybe a few.

Mathematically we can assume that the electric field is not even inside the wire, but only outside the wire, in the insulation.

The whole story made less and less sense, until with the invention of quantum mechanics they just chucked the whole thing. Quantum mechanics predicts the experimental results very very well, whenever it's a problem that's simple enough we know how to do the math. Nobody understands what it means. Nobody has a model which makes sense, to describe what the math says is happening. But it HAS to be the only correct description because it predicts so well. You don't need to understand it if you can calculate the correct results.

And that's where we stand today on Ohm's Law. Ohm's Law approximates what happens in electric circuits in some limited circumstances. You don't have to understand why it works, if you know when to apply it.

Comment: The classical explanation of the presence of an E field directed as j in the wire is that there are very few electrons on the surface of the wires that produce a field that superposed to the field of the generator result in E=j/sigma. This resulting field puts the large quantity of electrons inside the wire in motion. Drift velocity is qualitatively explained by the Drude model as a viscous limit velocity (but not quantitatively, for which QM and Fermi velocity need to be introduced). In summary: *very few* electron on the surface, *lots* of electrons inside (the skin effect is another thing)

Comment: @Peltio Thank you! That makes sense. Another turn of the helix of explanations....